# How to know which jsp's were included in the final rendering of the page

Tags: eclipse, jsp, debugging

I am currently maintaining  an app with literally a million jsp files. 
Is there a way to know which jsp files were included in rendering of a given page ? 
The element consoles of Firefox and chrome allow only to inspect the rendered elements but give no info on the jsp's included. I am remotely debugging using eclipse kepler (and tomcat), but I have no clue about which jsp pages can I set debug points as the final template for rendering has many conditions which allows the possibility of hundreds of jsps to be rendered

Comment: You mean there are like nested jsp:includes?

Comment: @developerwjk Yes, that is also the case. As well as, the nested 'graph' of jsps loaded is dependent on various conditions

Comment: If you only need a visual check on the client side in a development environment, you could programmatically put html comments at the beginning and end of each one with some kind of notation to indicate the jsp's name.  Then view source in your browser.

Comment: @Tap thats one way. The reason putting in comments or log statements is not possible is because of the sheer number of jsps involved. I would only keep guessing which file needs to have a comment (which is what I am doing now)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is something like this: Find a texteditor that can do mass replace over many files (e.g. [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/)) and use the regex replace capability to replace every occurance of `<jsp:include page="\([^"]+?\)" />` with `out.print("<br/>Including \1<br/>"); <jsp:include page="\1" />` Regex syntax can differ by tool, and if you're using parameters etc. you'll have more cases to replace, but this is the basic idea. Make sure to back up all the files first.

Comment: Would you please explain how \1 works in this scenario ?

Comment: In this syntax the \\( \\) mean the capture tokens, and \1 is the stuff that was captured.  So the \1 represents to the regex replace the pagename that was pulled from inside the quotes of page="whatever.jsp"