# tomcat : which JSP(s) got rendered to respond to a given http request

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, logging, rendering

Suppose I'm joining a new application team. This app uses a lot of JSPs and each JSP can include multiple other JSPs conditionally at runtime.

If I wanted to know which JSP was being rendered when I click on a given button/link, etc, how can I tell tomcat to log the same ?

summary : how can I ask tomcat to log the JSP that is being currently rendered ? The "localhost_access_log.txt" will show the various requests the http server(tomcat) is getting However, I'm after even more detailed information -- I want to know all the JSPs that are being rendered as part of a given request.

Comment: You mean without editing each of the JSPs, right?

Comment: yes. Context : I am new to a big application. There are many JSPs which include multiple other JSPs. some of them are static includes and some of them are dynamic(runtime) includes. I want to know which JSP gets rendered when I click on a given link, button, tab, etc.

Comment: The best answer I have is the one I put on this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895374/how-to-know-which-jsps-were-included-in-the-final-rendering-of-the-page which requires editing the pages (with a mass replace).